# Rails schema not updating with migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, schema

My `schema.rb` is no longer updating whenever I run `db:migrate`. It will update to the latest version but with none of the queries in my migrations and the comment:

> Could not dump table "games" because of following NoMethodError
>      undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

I accidentally manually dropped the table in console and was wondering if there was a way to resync my schema to the migrations? When I run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` the exact same schema generates.

Comment: The problem is that error which you refer to: you need to fix that.  Please include the code which that error is referring to in an EDIT to your question.

Answer (score -1):

In order to reload the database from the schema you should run:

```
$ rake db:schema:load
```

Then you can perform the pending migrations

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This advice absolutely needs the text **WARNING: this will nuke your entire development database, so make sure you have a backup first** in it somewhere :(